# Socket.io + Express + Node + Angular notifications

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I have an app where I'm trying to make a queue system for customers. I am trying to make it so that when a customer joins the queue, it notifies the store employees of the join and let's them know to get on it and help the customer as soon as possible.

I can't seem to get Socket IO to talk with my front end at all, though.

Here's the code I have, and I can't even get Node to recognize Socket as a library. I've followed 3 different tutorials, and tried them all, but I can't see what's being done wrong in my server code.

Here's what I'm doing in my server that's related to Socket.io

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io'); 


io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.emit('connection', "Connection created.")
    console.log("Socket.io is GO");

    socket.on('add customer', function(customer){
        console.log("Customer added", customer); 

    })

    socket.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log("NEW CUSTOMER IN THE QUEUE", data);
    });

});
```

I can't seem to get it to run in my server, and when it DID run, it didn't show any of the socket.on events that I had in there and it wouldn't console.log anything.

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone successfully gotten Socket to play nicely with Express and Angular together?

Comment: Have you put your server on listen mode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like your code is incomplete or maybe you didn't implement well.

I created an example using angular.js, express, and socket.io trying to replicate your requirement.

This is my server, `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection');

  socket.on('add-customer', function(customer) {
    io.emit('notification', {
      message: 'new customer',
      customer: customer
    });
  });
});

server.listen(4041, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 4041 port');
});
```

Then I created a public folder with the following files:

`public/index.html`

```
<!doctype>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="IndexController">
    <label>Please enter your name: </label>
    <input ng-model="currentCustomer.name"/>
    <button ng-click="join()">Join</button>
    <br/>

    <h1>New Customers: </h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="customer in newCustomers">{{customer.name}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

`public/app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/index.html'
  });
}]);

app.factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();

  return {
    on: function(eventName, callback){
      socket.on(eventName, callback);
    },
    emit: function(eventName, data) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data);
    }
  };
}]);

app.controller('IndexController', function($scope, socket) {
  $scope.newCustomers = [];
  $scope.currentCustomer = {};

  $scope.join = function() {
    socket.emit('add-customer', $scope.currentCustomer);
  };

  socket.on('notification', function(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.newCustomers.push(data.customer);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This got me much closer to working. Now I can tell that my socket connection is trying to go up to my server from Angular, but my server isn't see the connection and isn't pinging any of the console.logs I have in place.

Comment: Can you share your configuration of your angular app and server app?

Comment: yeah, what parts exactly would you like to see? I created a socket factory, called that in my CustomerCtrl, linked the addCustomer function to a button, and have that pinging back to my server. 

`io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection', socket);

  socket.on('addCustomer', function(customer) {
    io.emit('notification', {
      message: 'new customer',
      customer: customer
    });
  });
});

server.listen(4041, function() {
  console.log('Socket.IO server up and running on port 4040');
});`

That's my server code. The rest is pretty much what you had.

Comment: You could create a gist sharing for instance your isolated code just about communicating the server and client as I did on my example.

Comment: Here's a gist containing all the code related to my notifications. I still can't get my server to listen to my client side. I do believe I've gotten my client side to emit the right data, because it's telling me it's not finding the server.

Here's the gist - https://gist.github.com/dylanlott/756af5395df5e762c4c8

Comment: Please review this [gist](https://gist.github.com/wilsonbalderrama/21665da13ca8ebf8a39f), and follow the steps that the comments are telling you.
In your angular code in the factory part I saw that you have an error typo on the function declaration.

In your express code, you are listening two times the server, you should only listen once. Hope that this changes can help you to connect your angular app to socket io server, btw inspect as well the console from the browser, probably you are getting some errors there.

Comment: Wilson, how we would retrieve call back (true/ false) to check / validate

Comment: quick question we are hosting the socket server on port:4041, and not giving the port on angular app. Can the connection be established like that??

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your socket.io server so that it is listening on a specific port; without it listening, it can't watch for clients connection and emmitting messages. You should change your code as follows to fix this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//Existing Code

server.listen(1337, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:1337');
});
```